# Generate CSS Shapes at every refresh

Tags: css, css-shapes

My idea was to make a principal shape like a rectangular. Inside this rectangle I'd like to have, at every refresh, random shapes like triangles, cubes. Is this possible with the CSS or a I need a js script?

Comment: It's possible to render shapes in CSS.  The JS script would be needed if you wanted to control the behaviour on the page.  What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing yet. I know that it's possible but how can i generate random shapes with random dimensions and random color? Can you explain my idea with a js script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to include a 'random class' generator using a script. For example. below is a short example of 'how to assign a random class to a div on each load'. The basis is something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

  }
  var x = randomIntFromInterval(1, 3);
  var myclass;
  switch (x) {
    case 1:
      myclass = "classOne";
      break;
    case 2:
      myclass = "classTwo";
      break;
    case 3:
      myclass = "classThree";
      break;
  };
  $('div').addClass(myclass);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.classOne { /*simple square*/
  background: red;
}
.classTwo { /*simple triangle*/
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 300px solid blue;
}
.classThree { /*simple circle*/
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

**instructions**

hit 'run snippet' multiple times to see effect

---

Which uses a switch statement to add a class to a 'div' randomly each time the document loads.

**Note**

This example uses three possible classes, but this can be increased by:

1. increasing the max variable here: `randomIntFromInterval(1, 3);`
2. Adding extra use cases to the switch statement: `case 4:`, where 4 is the possible value returned from the function
3. Create a new class in your css
4. Add this `myclass` class name to your switch statement

On each subsequent load, there is an even possibility to be assigned to each of the different values.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better trying to generate shapes with SVG rather than CSS. But yes, you'll need JS to set up the random aspect.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use JS. The best option would be to create an array of classes, each representing a different shape. Then, on each page load, you assign a random class from the array to the element of your choice. But, as somebody else said, it would be better if the shapes were generated with SVG, and not CSS.